# Message to stop user to click the close(X) directly of web application using Telerik radwindowmanager

Tags: jquery, .net, telerik, messagebox, radwindow

A web application using Telerik RadWindowManager. I want to stop user on clicking the close button directly by throwing a message where he has option of Yes, No and Cancel.

If he hits Yes, means he can go to previous page saving some info to database, if No, He can go to previous page without save and cancel to remain in the same page. Please share your thought on this.

I try to add OnClientBeforeClose="OnClientBeforeClose" here and define the method OnClientBeforeClose. but it does not work

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="Singleton" runat="server"  Behaviors="Close, Move, Resize, Maximize">
        <Windows>
             <telerik:RadWindow ID="DialogMsg" 
                ReloadOnShow="true" OnClientClose="OnClientMsgclose"
                BackColor="Gray" Modal="true" runat="server" 
                NavigateUrl="../messages.aspx">
            </telerik:RadWindow>
        </Windows>
          <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="DialogAlertMsg" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"  OnClientClose="OnCloseOfAlertDialog"  EnableViewState="false" ReloadOnShow="true"
            BackColor="Gray" Modal="true" runat="server" Height="250" Width="350">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>          
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to achieve your scenario.

ASPX:

```
  <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="winmgr" runat="server">
            <Windows>
                <telerik:RadWindow ID="win1" runat="server" VisibleOnPageLoad="true" OnClientClose="OnClientClose">
                </telerik:RadWindow>
            </Windows>
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="confirmWindow" runat="server" VisibleTitlebar="true" VisibleStatusbar="false"
            Modal="true" Behaviors="None" Height="200px" Width="300px" Title="Confirm Delete">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 20px; width: 200px; float: left;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblConfirm" Font-Size="14px" Text="Are you sure ?" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" AutoPostBack="false"
                        OnClientClicked="confirmResult">
                    </telerik:RadButton>
                    <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonNo" runat="server" Text="No" AutoPostBack="false"
                        OnClientClicked="confirmResult">
                    </telerik:RadButton>
                    <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" AutoPostBack="false"
                        OnClientClicked="confirmResult">
                    </telerik:RadButton>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadWindow>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" />
```

JS:

```
function OnClientClose(sender, args) {
        $find("<%=confirmWindow.ClientID %>").show();
        $find("<%=RadButtonYes.ClientID %>").focus();

    }
    function confirmResult(sender, args) {
        var oWnd = $find("<%=confirmWindow.ClientID %>");
        oWnd.close();
        if (sender.get_text() == "Yes" || sender.get_text() == "No") {

            document.getElementById("<%=hdn.ClientID %>").value = sender.get_text();
            $find("<%=RadButton1.ClientID %>").click();
        }
    }
```

C#:

```
 protected void RadButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = hdn.Value;
        if(value=="Yes")
        {
          //your code
        }
        else if(value=="No")
        {
           //your code   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Saritha. The way you explained is really nice. But i think I missed out one point - I need to stop user clicking X (Close button at the right most corner beside minimize/restore).

Comment: if close button is not needed on which event you are trying to achieve the things

Answer (score 0):

This will show you how to confirm closing with JavaScript alone: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-application-confirm-closing.html
You can add additional code to the callback function to match your needs.

If you want three buttons - the above idea for a custom RadWIndow's ContentTemplate is the way to go, but you can do a lot more in JavaScript, not every button needs to postback.